# Prosodic stress

Tags: stress

What difference do different stress positions make to the meaning of the following sentence:

***What*** would you like?

What ***would*** you like?

What would ***you*** like?

What would you ***like***?

Comment: This is answered by typing ["prosodic stress" into Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosodic_stress#Prosodic_stress)

Comment: I saw Wikipedia before but I can't compare these with each other!

Comment: What do ***you*** think they mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A. They sell all kinds of toys in here. Pick something and I'll buy it for you.
>   B. I don't like anything round.
>   A. Well, what *would* you like then?
>   B. Something red.
>   A. Okay, something red, but *what* would you like?
>   B. I hate that bear.
>   A. I don't want to know what you hate. What would you *like*?
>   B. Jane likes drawing.
>   A. What would *you* like?

So the meanings break down as:

1. ***What*** would you like? (as opposed to some other property such as when or how you would like it)
2. What ***would*** you like? (as opposed to what you wouldn't or don't like)
3. What would ***you*** like? (as opposed to what another person would like)
4. What would you ***like***? (as opposed to what you might hate, or remember, or do something other than liking with)

Comment: What's the difference between 2 and 4?

Comment: @Gigili: In #2, the emphasis is on ***what** particular thing you want* (as opposed to a general category). In #4, the emphasis is on *what **you in particular** want* (as opposed to what someone else might want).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have them in different orders in my fake conversation, so maybe he means the second set? Let me cover that too. The difference in the 2nd set is that 2 is a response to a negative using the verb "like", and 4 is a response to a different verb altogether, like "hate" or "remember".

Comment: @Lunivore: Both you and OP would have done better if you'd *numbered* the four different versions. In fact, I think the most common context for stressing "like" here is if the other person has just named some choice with the clear implication that they've chosen it for some other reason (it's cheaper, more convenient, etc.), rather than because it's what they'd ***really** like*.

Comment: To both add to this answer, and in an attempt to answer @Gigili's comment -  it's worth noting that there's also a difference here between "I would like" as a politer form of "I want", and "I would like" as just meaning "I like", but in the conditional tense.  So "What **would** you like?" could mean "You **don't** want ice cream, so what **do** you want?"  By contrast, "What would you **like**?" means "I want to give you something that you will enjoy, so tell me something that you actually **like**, as opposed to something that you're just moderately in favour of".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Numbered. I would probably use and stress *really*, though, rather than *like*, in exactly the way you've done it.

Answer (score 2):

Such stress is about emphasis.

For all but the second one, the emphasis is to distinguish that stressed item from possible replacements. For example,

> What would you **like**?

means that they want to emphasize that the question is about what you *like* rather than what you really really love or could afford or what you already have; not what you would love but what you would like.

The second sentence

> What **would** you like?

is different in that there's really no alternative to the modal 'would' that makes sense (however one could imagine a situation where someone is talking about what one *should* like, and this is the alternative). But what I get out of the question is that the speaker is exasperated, the question 'What would you like?' (no emphasis) has been asked with poor responses so far.

Comment: I imagine "What would *you* like?* being about *you* rather than some other person, with the emphasis on the person rather than the verb. "What *would* you like?" is frequently said by exasperated parents on hearing, "Nooooo, not chocolate!" when offering a child ice-cream, for instance.